# Set spawner environment variables in custom Jupyterhub authenticator

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-lab, jupyterhub

I'm trying to use the remote authentication plugin for Jupyterhub, but also use it to save data into the `auth_state` property for the generated user.

Based heavily on the [Remote User Authenticator](https://github.com/cwaldbieser/jhub_remote_user_authenticator/blob/master/jhub_remote_user_authenticator/remote_user_auth.py), I have it working such that I create a user and create a session by reading a query parameter.

```
import os
import pprint
from jupyterhub.handlers import BaseHandler
from jupyterhub.auth import Authenticator
from jupyterhub.utils import url_path_join
from tornado import gen, web
from traitlets import Unicode

class InkspotUserLoginHandler(BaseHandler):

def get(self):
    inkspot_user = self.get_argument('user', None, True)
    inkspot_study = self.get_argument('studyFolder', None, True)
    if inkspot_user == "":
        raise web.HTTPError(401)
    if inkspot_study == "":
        raise web.HTTPError(401)

    user = self.user_from_username(inkspot_user)
    self.set_login_cookie(user)
    
    next_url = self.get_next_url(user)
    self.redirect(next_url)


class InkspotUserAuthenticator(Authenticator):
"""
Accept the authenticated user name from the user query parameter.
"""

def get_handlers(self, app):
    return [
        (r'/login', InkspotUserLoginHandler),
    ]

@gen.coroutine
def authenticate(self, handler, data):
    raise NotImplementedError()
```

However, I need to set environment variables in the spawner based on other query parameters sent to the authenticator. I've seen a [code example](https://jupyterhub.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/authenticators.html#using-auth-state) in the documentation on using `auth_state` as a way of storing data that be accessed by the `pre_spawn_start` hook, but can't see how that would work with the code I have. The code from the documentation looks like this:

```
class MyAuthenticator(Authenticator):
@gen.coroutine
def authenticate(self, handler, data=None):
    username = yield identify_user(handler, data)
    upstream_token = yield token_for_user(username)
    return {
        'name': username,
        'auth_state': {
            'upstream_token': upstream_token,
        },
    }

@gen.coroutine
def pre_spawn_start(self, user, spawner):
    """Pass upstream_token to spawner via environment variable"""
    auth_state = yield user.get_auth_state()
    if not auth_state:
        # auth_state not enabled
        return
    spawner.environment['UPSTREAM_TOKEN'] = auth_state['upstream_token']
```

My custom handler doesn't return anything, it redirects - which is probably why the authenticate method returns a `NotImplementedError`.

What am I missing that would allow me to use the `pre_spawn_start` hook in my existing code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to do it was to implement the authenticate method and pass query parameters to it as a data dictionary.

```
import os
import pprint
from jupyterhub.handlers import BaseHandler
from jupyterhub.auth import Authenticator
from jupyterhub.utils import url_path_join
from tornado import gen, web
from traitlets import Unicode

class InkspotUserLoginHandler(BaseHandler):

@gen.coroutine
def get(self):
    inkspot_user = self.get_argument('user', None, True)
    inkspot_study = self.get_argument('studyFolder', None, True)

    if inkspot_user == "":
        raise web.HTTPError(401)
    if inkspot_study == "":
        raise web.HTTPError(401)

    userDict = {
        'name': inkspot_user,
        'studyFolder': inkspot_study
    }

    user = yield self.login_user(userDict)
    next_url = self.get_next_url(user)
    self.redirect(next_url)


class InkspotUserAuthenticator(Authenticator):
"""
Accept the authenticated user name from the user query parameter.
"""

def get_handlers(self, app):
    return [
        (r'/login', InkspotUserLoginHandler),
    ]

@gen.coroutine
def authenticate(self, handler, data):
    return {
        'name': data['name'],
        'auth_state': {
            'studyFolder': data['studyFolder']
        }
    }

@gen.coroutine
def pre_spawn_start(self, user, spawner):
    """Pass inkspot data to spawner via environment variable"""

    auth_state = yield user.get_auth_state()
    if not auth_state:
        # auth_state not enabled
        self.log.debug('auth_state not enabled')
        return

    spawner.environment['STUDY_FOLDER'] = auth_state['studyFolder']
```